# Trying to make a android converting app but cant get the math coding right

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this code set up so when the user types into the EditText it will auto update rather then needing to click a button, how ever with this i can not figure out how to have basic math within the coding while still auto updating the ViewText with the answer. Please write it or give me lots of examples that work with my coding. thanks :)

my class

```
package xx.xx.xxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;



public class TemperatureActivity extends Activity {
    EditText input;
    TextView output;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.temperature_layout);


        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TemperatureInput);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CelsiusOutput);
        input.addTextChangedListener(watch);

    }
    TextWatcher watch = new TextWatcher() {@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }@Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }


        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int a, int b, int c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            output.setText(s);
            if (a == 9) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Maximum Limit Reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/BlueLagoon">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!--android:background="@color/GrayCloud"-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textColorHint="@color/Gray1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/TemperatureInput"
                android:hint="@string/hint"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/BlueKoi"/>
            <!--Divider Line-->
            <TextView
                android:alpha="0.60"
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/DarkBlue"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tab_padding_left"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/tab_padding_right"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:entries="@array/temperature"
            android:background="@color/BlueKoi"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- Screen Design for Photos -->
        <TextView
            android:text="PHOTOS HERE"
            android:id="@+id/Random"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_below="@id/Random"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@color/LightBlue1">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CelsiusName"
                        android:text="Celsius"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CelsiusOutput"
                        android:text="Right Text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"/>
                </FrameLayout>
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@color/LightBlue2">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/FahrenheitName"
                        android:text="Fahrenheit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/FahrenheitOutput"
                        android:text="Right Text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"/>
                </FrameLayout>
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@color/LightBlue1">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/KelvinName"
                        android:text="Kelvin"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/KelvinOutput"
                        android:text="Right Text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"/>
                </FrameLayout>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonConvert"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess "the MATH" involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, every primitive data in java (int, double, float etc.) has its own Wrapper Class (Integer, Double, Float etc.). This Wrapper provides useful methods one of them is parseType(String s) (Ex: Double.parseDouble("12.5")) which returns the value parsed from the string.

In your case if you want to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit in the onTextChange() you have to do it this way:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int a, int b, int c) {
    //Parsing String to double
    double cercuils = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
    double faherenheit = cercuils * 9/5 + 32;
    // faherenheit+"" -> converting double to String the easy way
    output.setText(faherenheit+"");
    if (a == 9) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Maximum Limit Reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.